# Token real synchronization from my website

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, metamask, synchronization

I like to integrate a real token synchronization (From distributer wallet account to user's wallet address the token need to transfer) in my website. My website needs to interact with the blockchain real token need to be transferred to the user's wallet address

I have check varoius Dapps not working on my website

If any have experience Real token synchronization let us know as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to include functionality in your website with which ERC20 tokens can be transferred from a distributer wallet to users' wallets.

This call all be achieved with some web3 scripts and with access to a node. So your web3 script creates transactions which transfer tokens to a given address, the script then connects to an Ethereum node and sends the transaction to the network.

For acquiring access to an Ethereum node you can either use a half-public one (such as Infura) or run your own with some client software (such as Geth).

Comment: I have created the smart contract using remix IDE and deployed my token in etherscan, all i need is to transfer my token to user's wallet via my webiste .....